# Hover the mouse on a element javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys i have an element that became ( on a third part website) active only when i put the mouse on it ,is there a way to simulate that in javascript?
the websites is like

```
<td class="textS col-date" nowrap="nowrap">  </td>
```

and i need to make it like the mouse is on it beacuse the website has a jquery option that allow you to click on it only if the mouse is on it.
in fact if in the chrome console i use : `document.getElementsByClassName("textS col-date")[0].click();` when i have the mouse on the elemnt i can click it , but if i don't have the mouse on the element it will says "undefined"

Comment: You might need to trigger one of the listeners on the element first, can you post the site (or the full code for a [mcve]) so we can figure out what's going on and come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `:focus` instead of `:hover` you can then do:

```
$('.textS.col-date').focus(function() {
   $(this).click();
});
```

Comment: i have tried to : var tdElement = document.querySelector('.textS.col-date');
tdElement.focus();document.getElementsByClassName("textS col-date")[0].click(); but i get undefined

Comment: That's because your selector is wrong! I updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: i get this : init [td.textS.col-date, prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: ".textS.col-date"] but it doesn't click

Answer (score 0):

well, basiclly u can just trigger an event.
with jQuery its pretty easy.

```
$("elementName").trigger("hover");
```

Comment: i get this init [prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: "textS col-date"] , but i'm unable to click it